# How to remove the Start Menu's context menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, start-screen

I'm trying to disable the right click on start menu apps in Windows 10. By tweaking few of StartMenu & Taskbar GPOs, I'm able to disable most of the context menu options except "turn live tile on/off". Is it possible to completely disable the right click only on start menu screen or disable the live tile on/off option on start screen?